# Database is not creating in postgres (psql)

Tags: postgresql, psql

I downloaded postgresql installer version 11 from official website for windows. 
when i enter psql and try to create database , database doesn't get created but it is creating by pgadmin4 with no problem

[image: Screenshot of psql]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi-colon at the end of the line.  You need to run:

```
CREATE DATABASE demo;
```

Answer (score 0):

you miss semicolon on the end of command.

you should to write `CREATE DATABASE demo;`

`psql` by default allows multilines statements, so any statement should be finished by special character and it is semicolon `;`